# How to insert a div in between flexbox rows and keep everything responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I tried using flexbox, as sweet as flexbox is for keeping it responsive, I quickly found out that it wasn't possible to selectively place a div in between rows when wrapping.

Tried doing it via inline-block rather than using flexbox, and it works fine if I ignore keeping the page responsive.  But that's the crux of the matter; I need for it to stay responsive.

Regardless of how many items are in the row, it should display the bio row below the row of where the row of the selected (clicked) picture is.  If a picture is selected in a different row, the original bio row is closed, and reopened in the row below the row of the newly selected picture.

This is the closest I've managed for flexbox:

```css
    .container {
        max-width: 1220px;
        border: 5px solid black;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 auto;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .item {
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
    }
    
    .one {
        background: #B5AC01;
    }
    .two {
        background: #ECBA09;
    }
    .three {
        background: #E86E1C;
    }
    .four {
        background: #D41E45;
    }
    .five {
        background: #D41EFF;
    }
    .six {
        background: #D4FF45;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item one"></div>
  <div class="item two"></div>
  <div class="item three"></div>
  <div class="item four"></div>
  <div class="item five"></div>
  <div class="item six"></div>
  <div class="item four"></div>
  <div class="item five"></div>
  <div class="item six"></div>
  <div class="item one"></div>
  <div class="item two"></div>
  <div class="item three"></div>
</div>
```

That didn't work out, as it's apparently a toughie to be able to find a row and insert a div in between those rows.  So I switched tacks and tried inline-block, only to find that while it's less complicated, it's still complicated.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1220px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0; 
}
    
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

.bio {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24pt;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 500px;
}

.selected {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.row {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0; 
}

.subrow {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0; 
}
    
.one {
  background: #B5AC01;
}

.two {
  background: #ECBA09;
}

.three {
  background: #E86E1C;
}

.four {
  background: #D41E45;
}

.five {
  background: #D41EFF;
}

.six {
  background: #D4FF45;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="subrow">
            <div class="item one">Pic</div>
            <div class="item two">Pic</div>
            <div class="item three selected">Clicked Pic</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subrow">
            <div class="item four">Pic</div>
            <div class="item five">Pic</div>
            <div class="item six">Pic</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bio">
        Bio goes here with pic
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="subrow">
            <div class="item four">Pic</div>
            <div class="item five">Pic</div>
            <div class="item six">Pic</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subrow">
            <div class="item one">Pic</div>
            <div class="item two">Pic</div>
            <div class="item three">Pic</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Haven't had much luck.  Would love a CSS/HTML only solution, but I'm open to Javascript/jQuery if that's necessary to pull it off.  Ideas?  Thanks in advance for your time.

Edit: someone posted a solution below suggesting using offsetTop to track wrappage to determine where to insert the bio row.  While it's not a CSS/HTML only solution, it's not a bad solution.  I'll experiment with the JS code some more tomorrow morning when I've had more sleep in me.

Comment: So what you are trying to achieve is display the bio row on every even position? or do you want it along the with the column elements in the same row?

Comment: If you look at the second code snippet (better yet, run it), you'll see one "pic" is selected, and immediately below that row in where that selected "pic" is, the bio row displays.  Ideally (but not yet implemented), if another picture is selected in the same row of the original selected pic, the bio row remains in same place.  If a picture is selected in a different row, then the bio closes and opens in a row below that selected picture.

Comment: So there is just one bio row which will be reused by all the pics? How about giving a bio row to each pic?

Comment: Correct, only one bio row is displayed at a time.  If a picture is selected in a different row, bio row closes in previous location and opens in a row below the newly selected picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(function(){

  $('.item').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    moveBio();
  });
  
  function moveBio() {

    var $bio = $(".bio");    
    var itemsPerRow = 0;

    $bio.hide(); // hide so doesn't affect calculations

    var firstItem = $('.item').eq(0);
    var itemTop = firstItem.position().top;
       
    $('.item').each(function(i) { // loop till we hit next row
      if($(this).position().top != itemTop) {
            itemsPerRow = i;
            return false;
        }   
    });
    
    selectedIndex = $(".item").index($('.selected')[0]);
    selectedRowNum = Math.floor(selectedIndex / itemsPerRow) + 1;
    
    $(".bio").insertAfter($(".item").eq((selectedRowNum * itemsPerRow) - 1)).show();    
  }
  
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $(".bio").hide(); // hide Bio so it doesn't interfere with the flex layout during resize
    clearTimeout(window.resizedFinished);
  
    window.resizedFinished = setTimeout(function(){
        moveBio(); // show Bio again now that resize has stabilised
    }, 250);
  });
  
});
```

```css
.container {
        max-width: 1220px;
        border: 5px solid black;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 auto;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .item {
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
    }
    
.bio {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24pt;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 500px;
}
    .one {
        background: #B5AC01;
    }
    .two {
        background: #ECBA09;
    }
    .three {
        background: #E86E1C;
    }
    .four {
        background: #D41E45;
    }
    .five {
        background: #D41EFF;
    }
    .six {
        background: #D4FF45;
    }
    .selected {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
        font-weight: 800;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item one"></div>
  <div class="item two"></div>
  <div class="item three"></div>
  <div class="item four"></div>
  <div class="item five"></div>
  <div class="item six selected"></div>
    <div class="bio">
        Bio goes here with pic
    </div>  
  <div class="item one"></div>
  <div class="item two"></div>
  <div class="item three"></div>
  <div class="item four"></div>
  <div class="item five"></div>
  <div class="item six"></div>
</div>
```

**Added dynamic browser resizing**

Here's an easier to resize example: http://jsbin.com/wamisiliza/edit?output

Comment: Added new jsbin example with dynamic browser resizing

Comment: See comment by me up there below my initial post that should help clarify how the bio works.  To save you time, I'll reiterate here.  It basically displays only one bio row.  If a picture is clicked on, it displays bio row below that row in where the clicked picture is.  If the bio row is to be displayed in a different row, the original bio row is closed and re-opened in the row immediately below that clicked picture.  Someone posted a solution suggesting the use of OffsetTop to determine wrappage to make it responsive.  Not a bad idea.

Comment: That's quite different to your question - "If there's 6 items per row, then display a bio row every six items. If it wraps to three items per row, then display a bio row every three items...."

Comment: Good catch, been a long day.  Fixed post to clarify.

Comment: Works as expected; wasn't expecting you to code the whole shebang, but much appreciated nonetheless!  I've marked this as the solution as I'll be going with it.  For future reference, there's no good way to do this with HTML/CSS only?

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question. I have no idea with CSS. But I came up with a quite complicated javascript method.

First get the array of all the items, just like your first example. And for each item, compare the `offsetTop` with the former item, if the values are not equal, insert a new Bio row between the two rows.

Sorry about the poor English, looking forword to a better answer.

Comment: Interesting solution.  When a picture is clicked on, could close bio row, use $(this) to get handle for the item, find the nearest .row via .closest, then run through the children to identify offsetTop for each item to determine wrappage, and use if then conditionals to determine where to insert bio.  That may just work.   I was hoping for a clean CSS solution, but I also can live with a JS solution.  I'll experiment with that, thanks for the idea!